# How to replace exact string using regex? In DrRacket

Tags: regex, string, racket

I've been working with some functions lately, and I have this one that it works for some cases, I need a general one. 
I need a regex such that it finds exactly what I'm looking for and not just traces of it. 
I have this, for example

```
>(regexp-replace* #rx"^123456$" "123456 FUBAR" "MATCH!")
"123456 FUBAR"
```

As you can see it's not replaceing '123456' with ''MATCH!

I tried using this:

```
> (regexp-replace* #rx"(?:^| )123456(?:$| )" "123456XXXXX FUBAR" "MATCH!")
"123456XXXXX FUBAR"
```

Which is EXACTLY what I DON'T need.

I've lurked thru some other posts but I think regexps in jScript and php work a little different since they use "/".

## Thanks in advice!

Edit: 
Well. The use of the following #rx:`^a` for example, does not work very well with strings like `(a 0 (a b))`.

```
> (regexp-replace* "^(a)" "(a 0 (a b)) FUBAR" "MATCH!")
"(a 0 (a b)) FUBAR"
```

I mostly need it to work it that way. :P

Comment: What does `(regexp-replace* #rx"^123456" "123456 FUBAR" "MATCH!")` do?

Comment: `> (regexp-replace* "^123456" "123456 FUBAR" "MATCH!")`

`"MATCH! FUBAR"` Indeed, it works. But I need it to work with something like...

`> (regexp-replace* "^a" "(a 0 b) FUBAR" "MATCH!")`

`"(a 0 b) FUBAR"`

Comment: I figured that was right, but it took me a while to find the right binary -- still was using MzScheme :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using word boundary (`\b`, should use pregexp syntax):

```
> (regexp-replace* #px"\\b123456\\b" "123456 FUBAR" "MATCH!")
"MATCH! FUBAR"
> (regexp-replace* #px"\\b123456\\b" "123456XXXXX FUBAR" "MATCH!")
"123456XXXXX FUBAR"
> (regexp-replace* #px"\\ba\\b" "(a 0 b) FUBAR" "MATCH!")
"(MATCH! 0 b) FUBAR"
> (regexp-replace* #px"a" "(a 0 (a b)) FUBAR" "MATCH!")
"(MATCH! 0 (MATCH! b)) FUBAR"
```

See [Regexp Syntax](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28part._regexp-syntax%29)

Comment: Thank you!! This works!! *Starts reading about word boundaries in regexps*